# Jinja2 - getting users selected value from a table and saving it as a variable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So, I am trying to develop a small site where the user selects a time from a drop-down box and that time select gets displayed on another page. I am struggling to capture the user's input from the drop-down box and send it to the function which generates the page that shows the users selected input.

I generate the drop-down list by creating a dropdown list and with a loop that receives an array as an input value I loop through that array and generate the options.

My question is, how do I capture the users selected option and pass it on to the show time function?

Is there a jinja2 native way of solving this?

**app.py** code

```
@app.route("/timeSelect")
def timeSelect():
    times = [1,2,4,8,12]
    return render_template("timeSelect.jinja", times=times)

@app.route("/showTime/<int:time>")
def showTime(time):
    return render_template("showtest.jinja",time=time)
```

**timeSelect.jinja** code

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option selected>Select Monitoring Time</option>

  {%for time in times%}
  <option value="{{time}}" >{{time}} hours</option>
  {%endfor%}
</select>   

<form method="get" action="{{ url_for('showTime', time=time)}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

**showtest.jinja** code

```
{{time}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a java-script based onClickEvent(). Which should be triggered when clicked on the value in drop-down and post data to back-end application and then capture response and process accordingly.

**Helpful Blog:-**
[Crud Using Ajax and JSON](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html)